# Combining row_num and group by between 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables that I'm trying to apply row_number to in a way that for each group, the row_number in table 2 picks up where table 1 left off.

Table1 (working as intended):

[image: Output]

```
SELECT DISTINCT Product, Item, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Product, Item)
FROM Table1 (NOLOCK)
```

Table2: Desired Output:

[image]

Current Code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Product, Item, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Product, Item)+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1)
FROM Table2 (NOLOCK)
```

[image: Current Output]

Comment: I highly recommend *not* using `nolock` unless you absolutely need to.

Comment: Please avoid using images in your questions, unless it's a question about a GUI bug. Instead, use formatted text to properly show your [sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and expected results. Thanks.

Comment: I'm lost on the logic.  You say you want to change the row numbers, but the number of rows is changing as well.  What is the logic for filtering or aggregation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is the followong statement:

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (Product varchar(1), Item int)
INSERT INTO Table1 (Product, Item)
VALUES ('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 1), ('B', 2), ('B', 3)

CREATE TABLE Table2 (Product varchar(1), Item int)
INSERT INTO Table2 (Product, Item)
VALUES ('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 1)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   Product, 
   Item, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Item) AS Rn
FROM Table1

SELECT 
  t2.Product, 
  t2.Item, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.Product ORDER BY t2.Item) + t1.[Count] AS Rn
FROM Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT Product, COUNT(*) AS [Count]
   FROM Table1 
   GROUP BY Product
) t1 ON t2.Product = t1.Product
```

Result:

```
Product Item  Rn
A       1     1
A       2     2
B       1     1
B       2     2
B       3     3

Product Item Rn
A       1    3
A       2    4
B       1    4
```

Comment: This is beautiful! Thank you!